# How to show products description without tabs

Tags: magento2, product

I am using Magento 2.3 with Porto theme, by default Magento shows description and rating information in a tab.
How to remove/disable tabs and show tabs data straight?

Comment: Then you need to do the customization here for this one.

Comment: Yes Will need customization but, I am not sure which file to update

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @ZealousWeb thanks for your answer. I was using Porto theme so I override the product view template file inside my child theme and updated it to remove tab code. Here is the screenshot https://tinyurl.com/yfncqbra

Comment: If my answer is useful then please upvote this so other community member can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do customisation in below files. AS well as need to write css to look proper according to your theme.

Here i have done in one of my sample magento.

> Step 1: Please write below code in your theme's
> catalog_product_view.xml file

```
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.media" after="-"/>
```

**If you have custom container then move element in your custom container from xml file.**

> Step 2: Override file details.phtml from path
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/ in
> your theme

Write below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details $block */
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')) :?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name) :?>
                <?php
                $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                if (!trim($html)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title">
                    <span class="data switch" id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $label ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content">
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Step 3: Changes in css as per sample magento

https://prnt.sc/14nd5pb

```
Output :- https://prnt.sc/14nevfl
```

Please do change in css as per your theme to look proper.

Please check and let me know on this